# Use jQuery to hide bootstrap div that is visible-phone?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

It seems that using responsive tags like visible-phone with bootstrap disables the jquery function of hide and show. I'm attempting to hide a div on document ready that can only be seen on phones (visible-phone). On a button press, this same div will be shown and another div that is also visible-phone will be hidden.

Unfortunately, hide and show does nothing when a class of visible-phone is present. If I remove visible-phone, the jQuery works as it should. The problem is, I don't want these divs displayed when not in a phone-sized browser.

Here's my script and divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#phone-num').hide();
    $('#num').click(function() {
        $('#phone').hide();
        $('#phone-num').show();
    });
    $('#num-back').click(function() {
        $('#phone-num').hide();
        $('#phone').show();
    });
});
</script>

<div id="phone" class="visible-phone">
<button style="margin-left: 60%;" class="phone5" id="num">#</button>
</div>

<div id="phone-num" class="visible-phone">
<button style="margin-left: 80%;" class="phone5" id="num-back"><i class="icon-reply"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use media queries for phone-sized resolutions and set the div's as display:none instead of using jQuery to do it?

Comment: I'm not trying to hide and show automatically at phone-sized resolutions. I'm trying to provide alternate information on a button press.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity workaround:

```
$('#phone-num').css('opacity', 0);

$('#num').click(function () {
    $('#phone').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#phone-num').css('opacity', 1);
});

$('#num-back').click(function () {
    $('#phone-num').css('opacity', 0);
    $('#phone').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle, if the buttons don't appear then you may need to make the result pane smaller to that the media query recognizes it as a phone resolution.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFd2n/4/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by wrapping the `visible-phone` element inside another container, which can then be hidden, e.g.:

```
<div id="phone-num">
  <div class="visible-phone">
    <button style="margin-left: 80%;" class="phone5" id="num-back">
        <i class="icon-reply"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the thing only is shown on phones, and when declaring the parent element as invisible, the inner divs are hidden as well.

```
$('#phone-num').hide()
```